# Hello World Rust program compiles, but execution results in No authorization error

Tags: rust

I have just started with the Rust book. Compiling works fine, but running it results in the error "No authorization".

I have the file

```
fn main() {
  println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

and compiled it with

```
rustc main.rs
```

the binary file "main" has been created, there was no error output (or any output) from the compiler. but

```
./main
```

results in

```
bash: ./main: Keine Berechtigung (which means "No authorization")
```

As you can see I am the owner of the file and it is executable:

```
ls -l 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 monika monika 2491696 Okt  6 21:12 main
-rw-r--r-- 1 monika monika      45 Okt  6 20:31 main.rs
```

I have tried: Uninstalling and reinstalling Rust, rebooting the computer.

I have not used sudo at any point nor run any part (installation, file creation, compilation) as another user.

Comment: This question was [cross-posted to users.rust-lang.org](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/running-first-program-results-in-no-authorization-error/33343).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told us anything about what operating system you're on, but this error appears to be the errno value `EACCES`.  The reasons that `EACCES` can be given when running an `exec` function on Linux are the following:

- Search permission is denied on a component of the path.
- The file or script interpreter isn't a regular file.
- Execute permission is denied for the script or ELF interpreter.
- The fileystem is mounted `noexec`.

In this case, the most likely problem is that you're working on a file system that is mounted `noexec`.  On some systems, `/tmp` is mounted `noexec`, and in some large installations (such as universities), `/home` is as well.  You should run `mount` (or your operating system's equivalent) to find out the mounted file systems and their mount options, and then pick a file system that isn't mounted `noexec`, assuming that's the case.

The other problem could be that the directory doesn't have search permissions, in which case you should look up the directory hierarchy and make sure the execute bit is set for each of those directories for your user, or to switch to a directory which does have those perimssions.

This isn't really a Rust issue; you'd likely have this with a C program as well.  The problem is almost certainly an issue with configuration or permissions on your system.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. My second internal hard drive, on which my Rust folder is located, was mounted `noexec` by Kubuntu. Yes, all binary executables were affected, my other coding is mostly in Java so I never noticed.